# Copy table with a column combo box into a new table having the combo box column as text box

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, textbox

In MS Access, I have a table populated from sharepoint. One of the columns is combo box. I need this column to be converted to text box automatically, as I need to run some queries after, and they do not work if one of the columns is combo box.

- I have tried to change the type in the populated table, but the change can't be done as it is populated from sharepoint and thus read-only.
- I have tried to copy and paste into a new table, and then make the change, but the combo box column doesn't get pasted (only blanks are transferred)

Comment: I don't think this makes a whole lot of sense.  Can you rephrase your question?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: So the field is a lookup on SharePoint list? This means table also has lookup setting on field? I don't use SharePoint. Why would a query not work with this? What does 'not work' mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?